# Selenium - Block popup using firefox driver

Tags: selenium, popup, block, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to block popup in selenium using firefox driver.

has anyone done anything like this? i have had tried by loading extension but no success.

Can anyone help here?

Thanks!

Regards,
Kalpesh Patel

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your browser profile and block popup there. Pass your profile as a parameter while creating instance of your browser. check the code below:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("Your-profile-name");
profile.setPreference( "intl.accept_languages", "no,en-us,en" ); 
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.example.com/");
```

Note: I consider that you already know the concept of profile in browser.

Comment: Yeap, I am aware of it. I tried with my profile earlier as well which didnt block the popups. :( I will give a shot again ans see if it works.

Thanks

Comment: what property will block the popup ?